# How make new instances of a class in Python 3?

Tags: list, class, oop, python-3.x, append

I came up on this weird behaviour in python. I want to make two difference instances of the class `Numbers`:

```
class Numbers:
   numberList=[]

   def __init__(self, *arg):
      for number in arg:
         self.numberList.append(number)


numbers=Numbers(4, 8)    # Instance 1
numbers=Numbers(7, 5, 3) # Instance 2
print(numbers.numberList)
```

Output:

```
[4, 8, 7, 5, 3]
```

Expected output:

```
[7, 5, 3]
```

I thought the part of my code where I do class instantiation would be equal to the usage of the keyword `New` found in other languages. However the outcome is totally different. Why is that? I want `instance 1` to be totally **replaced** with `instance 2`, not concatenate the two.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, `numberList` is class variable that is shared by all class instances.

```
>>> class Numbers:
...     numberList = []
... 
>>> n1 = Numbers()
>>> n2 = Numbers()
>>> Numbers.numberList is n1.numberList
True
>>> Numbers.numberList is n2.numberList
True
```

Change as follow to get per-instance instance variable (called *data attribute* in Python):

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self, *arg):
        self.numberList = []
        for number in arg:
            self.numberList.append(number)
```

Comment: Or just `self.numberList = list(args)`